# Since last week I am struggling with this issue. I am trying to insert an ASSET IMAGE in my flutter application but it doesn't work as expected

Tags: flutter

My asset images don't load. But if I try a network image, it loads properly.

Here is the code:  `const Image(image: AssetImage('images/logo.png')),`

The error:  `EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════ I/flutter ( 6396): The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec: I/flutter ( 6396): Unable to load asset: "images/logo.png". I/flutter ( 6396): Exception: Asset not found I/flutter ( 6396):  I/flutter ( 6396): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: I/flutter ( 6396): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.loadBuffer (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:369:7) I/flutter ( 6396): <asynchronous suspension> I/flutter ( 6396): #1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:811:18) I/flutter ( 6396): <asynchronous suspension> I/flutter ( 6396):  I/flutter ( 6396): Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "images/logo.png") I/flutter ( 6396): Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#daa66(), name: "images/logo.png", scale: I/flutter ( 6396):   1.0) I/flutter ( 6396): ══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════`

[This is my asset folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHdYm.png),

[This is my pubspec.yaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SS2D1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your asset folder indentation having issue please align assets with uses-material-design
[image]

Comment: Please mark as accepted answer and upvote for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your `pubspec.yaml` is creating path for  images like `"assets/images/logo.png"`. And you are passing it only `images/logo.png`.

The the actual issue is you created wrong directory.
Just create **assets** directory inside your project, and then create another directory name **images** inside **assets** directory.
So you base path will look like `assets/images/`

***Now you are able to solve this issue.***

To solve this issue you need to add `assets` to your passing string in `AssetImage`

**Code:**

`const Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/logo.png'))`,

then run `flutter pub get` command and restart your application.